# SFTP server refuses connection when a user restricted to a folder

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have Raspberry Pi 3 and I want to be able to send and receive files through SFTP. I was able to set everything up and I can connect to my Raspberry Pi. However, I want to restrict or limit user to a specific directory not the whole system. For some reason, I am not able to do it. I searched online and found many tutorials on it, but every time I applied the tutorials I can't connect to my pi using SFTP client. If I remove all the changes I made in SSHD_CONFIG file, then it connects to my pi again. Any chances I make to SSHD_CONFIG file, SFTP client refuses to connect to my PI. Error messages I get is Connection Error. Server refused to connect.

Here is one of many tutorial I followed.

```
groupadd sftpgroup

usermod -G sftpgroup user1

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftpgroup
   ChrootDirectory /home
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   X11Forwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding no

systemctl restart sshd

chmod 700 /home/user1
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/1022432/restricting-user-group-to-specific-folder-in-win2016-server

https://kifarunix.com/restrict-sftp-user-access-to-specific-directories-in-linux/

https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-sftp-user-home-directories-using-chroot/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***ChrootDirectory
Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication. All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group. After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.***

According to the manual, the reason why my sftp client refused to connect after I made the modifications to SSHD_CONFIG file was because the ChrootDirectory was not ROOT-OWNED. sftp will only allow connection to path to folder that are owned by root user. So, I did the following.

```
sudo chown root:root -R /home/user/
sudo chmod 755 -R /home/user/
```

Then, my sftp client connected with my SSHD_CONFIG modification. The error I got had nothing to do with the changes I added to SSHD_CONFIG file.

I am posting the answer that worked for me and it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is mandatory, but you are missing the / after `/home`
That is the only major difference that I find between your configuration sample and mine.